# TensorFlow: Using a C++ protobuf package for Python 3.5?

Tags: ubuntu, pip, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, python-3.5

The documentation for TensorFlow [states](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#protobuf-library-related-issues), the performance for the native Python protobuf implementation can be 10-50 times slower than the C++ version. I am compiling TensorFlow from source, following the [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#create-the-pip-package-and-install). I would like to use the C++ version of protobuf. I am building TensorFlow on Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64) and Python 3.5.

Note that binary package suggested in the documentation won't install in a Python 3.5 environment:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl
protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

EDIT: I discovered that a simple rename of the file made it possible to install the package in Python 3.5. This however, did not solve my problem as the implementation still claims to be 'python',

```
python -c "from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation; print(api_implementation._default_implementation_type)"
```

Comment: I vote to close. What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. The question was stated in the subject.